# How can I make money from an artist like Madonna doing well?

Tags: investing

If I thought that an artist like Madonna would be getting a big break soon, how would I best invest my money to profit of her break?

Maybe the good news could look like an expectation of there being 3 number 1 hits in one year and they will be high in the standings for the next 2 years (like top 20).

I expect this to happen within the next 10 years, and am willing to wait
(lock in my money).

Let's assume I got this information from trusted sources (of course nothing is set in stone).

I just don't know how one could make use of such information.
The only thing I can think off, is buy stocks from her record label. But since they are so big, with so many different artists, I doubt the return would be worth it.
Is there a way to get closer to an artists value?

There is a little doubt about the worth of the "information" as well.
Since Madonna is already such a huge name, maybe those hits wont really impact her brand/name/value all that much? So in short, would it even be worth it to try to profit off of this information?

Comment: Related question, is there a way to sell short on Madonna?

Comment: I'd be very interested in seeing if there is an answer _other_ than investing in the record label (which, as you say, is fraught with other issues).  I don't think I can see one, but I'm definitely not an expert.

Comment: Unless the artist has incorporated themselves and is selling shares, or you can find some other way to convince them to accept funding from you in exchange for a fragment of future sales (underwrite tr=he costs of producing an album, perhaps), I really doubt that there's any good way to make this an investment. You can of ckurse find someone willing to make a bet..

Answer (score 5):

In 1997, the late David Bowie famously worked with a financier to innovate on a bond issue to be paid back by the royalties on his back catalog, [Bowie Bonds](http://www.billboard.com/articles/business/6843009/david-bowies-bowie-bonds-55-million-wall-street-prudential)  Several contemporary musicians followed suit, but Madonna was not one of them.  At some point this may change and Madonna or the label that owns part of the catalog may issue bonds backed by royalties.

Madonna's catalog pre-2007 is owned by [Warner Music](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/10/11/business/media/11madonna.html?_r=0) which in 2011 was sold by Time-Warner to a private equity company [Access Industries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Industries#Warner_Music_Group).

Madonna's post 2007 music including the latest 2015 release is in partnership with LiveNation, a publicly traded company LYV.

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago, I stumbled across a little-known band and thought about buying tickets to their upcoming show. The tickets were an absolute steal, maybe $20 each because no one had heard of them but I didn't bother at the time. Figured I'd wait until closer to the tour date.

Fast forward to about a month before the show. They had released a very popular single that summer and tickets were being sold online for well over $100. I remember thinking "if only I knew these guys were going to be a big name one day". I suppose I could have made a killing buy purchasing tons of tickets and selling them just before the event at a mad profit.

That's about the only scenario I can think of.

Comment: +1, though this doesn't really jibe with the OP's stated time frame of one to ten years. Plus, [scalping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_resale) is frowned upon or even illegal in some jurisdictions.